# Picasso - cache specific fade animation

Tags: android, picasso

This seems like a simple idea, but I imagine the back-end might be complicated. Using a `ListView`, is there a way to use the `.noFade()` parameter ONLY if the imaged is already cached in memory? I'd like it to fade in if it's being loaded from the Internet, but if it's already cached then it should display immediately.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the image into your own Target Interface, and check against the LoadedFrom parameter:

```
Target target = new Target() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap arg0, LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
         if(LoadedFrom.MEMORY == loadedFrom){
             //TODO -- noFade
         } else {
             //TODO -- fade
         }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Secondary question: how do I get this `Target` to work with an `ImageView` in a `ViewHolder` pattern?

Comment: You could extend ImageView and make it implement the Target Interface, or just add a Target as a field in your ViewHolder that you use as a delegate to your ViewHolder's ImageView once the image has loaded.

Comment: This is probably the way to go, however picasso's implementation is supposed to hook into the `View`'s lifecycle to manage the requests and caching. Implementing your own `Target` means you're giving up on that functionality and would also have to manage it on your own.